# Javascript functional composition/sequencing

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition, sequencing

I'm trying to understand composition and "sequencing" concept in Javascript with an exercise:

> Def. "composition" `compose(f,g)(x) = f(g(x))`
>
> Def. "sequencing" `sequence(f,g)(x) = g(f(x))` for more args `sequence(f,g)(...args) = g(f(...args))`

```
const sequence2 = (f1, f2) => (...args) => f2( f1(...args) );
const sequence = (f1, ...fRest) => fRest.reduce(sequence2, f1);

const f1 = (a, b) => {
    console.log(`[f1] working on: ${a} and ${b}`);
    return a + b;
}

const f2 = a => `Result is ${a}`;

const sequenceResult = sequence(f1, f1, f2)(1, 2, 5);
console.log(sequenceResult);
```

The console shows:

```
[f1] working on: 1 and 2
[f1] working on: 3 and undefined
Result is NaN
```

*It seems that the second function in the sequence can't access the args: there is something I'm missing or it's the wrong approach for dealing with parameters? (The sequence function works for functions without params).*

Here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6p3kbu4/)

Comment: In `g(f(x))`, `g` cannot (and is not supposed to!) access `x`. Everything is normal and behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the second function in the sequence can't access the args

Yes, that's normal and expected. According to the definition you gave,

```
sequence(f1, f1, f2)(1, 2, 5);
```

is equivalent to

```
f2(f1(f1(1, 2, 5)));
```

Of course neither `f2` nor the outer `f1` can access the arguments that are passed to the inner `f1`.

Comment: Thanks, the equivalence explained very well why only the return value is available to outer functions.

Answer (score 1):

Functions only return a single value. There are two ways to augment functions by multiple return values:

- return an array like tuple
- instead of returning call a continuation

Here is a fun implementation for the latter, which is explicitly not meant for any production code:

```js
const pipek = g => f => x => y => k =>
  k(g(x) (y) (f));

const addk = x => y => k =>
  (console.log("apply addk to", x, y), k(x + y));

const main = pipek(addk)
  (addk)
    (2)
      (3)
        (k => k(4)); // we have to pass the 4th argument within the continuation

console.log(main(x => x)); // escape from the continuation
```

Please note that all functions are curried and that I used the term `pipe`, which is the usual term for reverse function composition in JS.

Comment: Thanks, "return an array like tuple" is some kind of solution.